# polars - diff - ignore null in shift?

Tags: python, python-polars

within a group, I need to find the difference between the previous non-null value.
Example:

| id | value | expected result | explanation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 10 | null | 10- oob |
| a | null | null | null -10 |
| a | 30 | 20 | 30 - 10 |
| b | 10 | null | 10 - oob |
| b | null | null | null - 10 |
| b | null | null | null - null |
| b | 40 | 30 | 40 - 10 |

For context: this is an intermediate step. The final goal is to fill the nulls, but not linearly as every line has a timestamp, so I will have to distribute the difference between 2 non-null values according to the time difference between each line. Eg for "a" the time diff between the first and the second row could be 10 seconds, and the between the second and third row could be 30 seconds. So when distributing the difference of 20. I would need to assign 20 * ( 10 / 40 ) to the first row and 20 * ( 30 / 40 ) to the second row.

So I applied the following in polars

```
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "id": ["a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b"],
    "value": [10, None, 30, 5, 10, None, None, 40]
})
df_delta = df.with_columns(
    delta = pl.col("value").diff(1).over("id")
    ,delta_ignore = pl.col("value").diff(1, null_behavior="ignore").over("id")
)
```

Notice I applied the null_behaviour parameter ignore on the second column. However, the result I get is:

| id | value | delta | delta_ignore |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 10 | null | null |
| a | null | null | null |
| a | 30 | null | null |
| b | 5 | null | null |
| b | 10 | 5 | 5 |
| b | null | null | null |
| b | null | null | null |
| b | 40 | null | null |

Thanks for the help.

Addendum: I currently work around it by extending my window partition to

```
.over("id", pl.col("value").is_not_null())
```

Comment: In your example the first row of b says you expect 5 but shouldn't it be null because the previous is oob?

Comment: @DeanMacGregor correct. I had some issues getting the table in the post and in my many tries it got mixed up. Thanks for noticing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a combination of forward_fill to deal with nulls and one shift.

This seems to work

```
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "id": ["a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b"],
    "value": [10, None, 30, 5, 10, None, None, 40]
})
(
    df
    .with_columns(delta=pl.col('value')-((pl.col('value')
                                          .forward_fill()
                                          .shift()).over('id')))
)
shape: (8, 3)
┌─────┬───────┬───────┐
│ id  ┆ value ┆ delta │
│ --- ┆ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ str ┆ i64   ┆ i64   │
╞═════╪═══════╪═══════╡
│ a   ┆ 10    ┆ null  │
│ a   ┆ null  ┆ null  │
│ a   ┆ 30    ┆ 20    │
│ b   ┆ 5     ┆ null  │
│ b   ┆ 10    ┆ 5     │
│ b   ┆ null  ┆ null  │
│ b   ┆ null  ┆ null  │
│ b   ┆ 40    ┆ 30    │
└─────┴───────┴───────┘
```

Comment: thanks very helpful.
If I make my question more generic:

"how can I, within a group, find the first next/previous value of a column where the rows meet certain conditions", how would that go in Polars (I am a SQL-guy very new to python/polars).

Comment: I'm having a hard time thinking of that in a general case, could you make a new question with an example?

Comment: added the full challenge here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77099610/polars-fill-null-using-rule-of-three-based-of-filtered-set
your answer helped me calculated the gap value

I need to do a few calculations using the prev and next value for this I think, hence the generic question "I need to select values from the next and previous row where the value is not null'